# Expressjs regExp with params

Tags: regex, node.js, express

Hi I am trying to get my Regular expression working in expressJS.
If i go in to /se/home/helloworld it will always trigger the first one "Home" and not the "Test". How to solve this?

Finely it must handel this tree path.

```
/se/home/:user
/se/home/:user/:notes
/se/home/:user/:notes/:someting
```

This is what I have managed so far...

```
app.get(new RegExp("^(\/(se|en))?\/home\/"), function(req, res, next) {
    console.log("Home");
    res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});

app.get(new RegExp("^(\/(se|en))?\/home\/([^/]+)"), function(req, res, next) {
    console.log("Test");
    console.log(req.params);

    res.render('index', { title: 'Express test' });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use an anchor with the first regex to make sure there is nothing else after `home/`:

```
RegExp("^(/(se|en))?/home/$")
```

Or, use a string literal:

```
/^(\/(se|en))?\/home\/$/
```

Otherwise, you will get a match.

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/oK5lP6/2)

Comment: Please do not hesitate to drop a comment in case anything about my approach is unclear to you.